# What is the complexity class of this problem without Cramer's conjecture?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, algorithms, computational-complexity, computational-number-theory

The problem 'Given $0<a<b$ is there a prime in the interval $[a,b]$?' is in $\mathsf{NP}$. If we assume Cramer's conjecture the problem is in $\mathsf{P}$ since if $b-a>(\log a)^{2+\epsilon}$ at any fixed $\epsilon>0$ then there is a prime by Cramer's conjecture and if the interval is smaller we can utilize $\mathsf{AKS}$ primality test to test all integers in the interval $[a,b]$.

Without Cramer's conjecture what can we say about the problem?

Is the problem in $\mathsf{BPP}$ or at least in $\mathsf{P/poly}$?

**Update** [Qi Cheng](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-36494-3_15) provided a subexponential randomized algorithm for ultimate complexity of factorial. Namely it produces a number $m_n n!$ at some $m_n\in\mathbb Z$ in $e^{O(\sqrt{(\log n)(\log \log n)})}$ time (but space is larger because of the number of bits in $n!$) utilizing randomness on a machine with large enough wordsizes and word operations are in unit time.

> Is it possible to utilize such an algorithm and perhaps properties of factorials and integers to produce at least an $\mathsf{i.o.}$-$\mathsf{BPTIME}[2^{o(n)}]$ or at least an $\mathsf{i.o.}$-$\mathsf{TIME}[2^{o(n)}]/\mathsf{poly}$ algorithm to the problem perhaps under a suitable weakening of the Turing model?

**Is there evidence for either this problem $\mathsf{NP}$-hard or not if Cramer's conjecture is not true?** I understand the suggestion I provide is remote.

**UPDATE**

Let $k$-divisor of an integer $N$ be a divisor which is a product of $\leq k$ (not necessarily distinct) primes ($1$ is not a prime).

Problem $3$ below is the problem about primes. [Problem $1$ is $\mathsf{NP}$-hard](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/4769/an-np-complete-variant-of-factoring) and Problem $2$ is the factoring problem.

Problem $1$: Given an integer $N$ and an interval $[a,b]$ is there an $\infty$-divisor of $N$ in $[a,b]$?

Problem $2$: Given an integer $N$ and interval $[a,b]$ is there an $1$-divisor of $N$ in $[a,b]$?

Problem $3$: Given an interval $[a,b]$ is there an $1$-divisor of $b!$ in $[a,b]$?

Comment: Basically the answer to your first question is "not much".  This was basically the Polymath4 project https://asone.ai/polymath/index.php?title=Finding_primes which only produced some modest results at https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2869058

Comment: Thank you........ provided an update.

Comment: What does i. o. mean? Also, what does Chang's algorithm have to do with the problem at hand?

Comment: i.o means infinitely often. May not work for all intervals $[a,b]$ but works infinitely often.

Comment: If $m_n=1$ then we have information about factorials then perhaps the ratio $b!/a!$ gives something is the 'hopeful' possibility. In addition I am saying perhaps we can weaken the Turing model and so some reasonable generalization gives something.

Comment: Is there evidence this problem is not $\mathsf{NP}$-hard? I understand the suggestion I provide is remote.

Comment: $\mathsf{NP}$ in quasipolynomial time suffices to produce a deterministic algorithm for primes of desired properties at a gap as large as $2^{(\log\log n)^c}$ at any $c>1$ and Cramer's conjecture of prime gap of $O(\mathsf{polylog}(n))$ without any special properties of the prime itself is unnecessary. It suffices to derandomize few non-trivial randomized algorithms.

Comment: $\mathsf{NP}$ in quasipolynomial time suffices to derandomize https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/4769/an-np-complete-variant-of-factoring under a weaker possibility of quasipolynomial prime gap.

Comment: If we think these should be in linear complexity I think Cramer's conjecture is not avoidable.